# My While loop doesn't give the value its supposed to give

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

We've been given a assignment at school and the
while loop at the end of the code doesn't seem to give the value I expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[50],storage[50][50]={0},temp[50]={0};
    printf("Input Formula without space:");
    gets(str);
    int x=0, y=0,z=0,w,i,top=-1,max=strlen(str);
    
    
    for(i=0;i<max;i++){
        printf("Eyyyyyy");
        top+=1;
        switch(str[top]){
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '-':
        case '+':
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '9':storage[x][y]=str[top];x++;break;
        case ')': 
            if (x-3<0)
                break; 
            else{
                while(storage[x-3][y]!=0){
                    temp[y]=storage[x-3][y];
                    y++;
                    printf("Hey");}; 
                storage[x-3][y]='(';
                while (temp[y]!=0){
                    storage[x-3][y+1]=temp[y];
                    y++;
                };
                for (z=2;z>=0;z--){
                    while (storage[x-z][y]!=0){
                        w=strlen(storage[x-3]);
                        storage[x-3][w]=storage[x-z][y];
                    }
                }
            }
            x-=3;
            break;
            
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%c",storage[0][i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<20:i++){
        printf("%c",storage[0][i]);
    }
    while(storage[x][y]!=0){
        printf("%c",storage[0][y]);
        y++;
    }
    
}
```

I'd like to ask for some help on how do I make the while loop work. It doesn't give me any errors when compiling its just the value on while loop doesn't show up. only the other `printf`s before that.

Comment: Now seems like a great time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Note that it will be easier if you have a consistent indentation, and don't put multiple statements on a single line.

Comment: You may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471)

Comment: regarding the statement: `for(i=0;i<20:i++){`   This does not compile!   The parameters MUST be separated via a semicolon `;`, not a colon `:`

Comment: the function: `strlen()` return a `size_t` not an `int`

Comment: regarding: `gets(str);`  The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for decades and completely removed from the C language back in 2009.  Strongly suggest using `fgets()` (read the [MAN page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) as the parameter list (and some other details) are different)

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%c",storage[0][i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<20:i++){
        printf("%c",storage[0][i]);
    }`  Why print the same data twice?

Comment: regarding statements like: `for(i=0;i<20;i++){`  What is the importance/meaning of the 'magic' number `20`?   Especially since the actual (possible) length of the input is 48.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the `while()` statement at the end of the posted code:

```
while(storage[x][y]!=0){`
```

what are the initial values of `x` and `y`?

Since those values are already 'maxed out' the selection of `storage[x][y]` is past the end of the array `storage'

Suggest properly initializing those index values before entering the `while()` loop